# Write one string to a socket within 10 seconds or another string if the time is out

Tags: java, multithreading, socket, scheduled-tasks, timeout

I have implemented a method which will send one data to the server if it (Raspberry Pi Pin Input HIGH, in this case) occurs within 10 seconds. If this doesn't happen within 10 seconds then I should send some other data.

This implementation works for me, but I think that there should be another better implementation.

```
ScheduledExecutorService timeoutScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

ScheduledFuture<?> timeoutHandler = timeoutScheduler.schedule(() -> {
    try {
        socketConnection.writeData("String that should be sent if time is out");
        turnstileClosed.removeAllListeners();
        timeoutScheduler.shutdownNow();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, 10_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

turnstileClosed.addListener((GpioPinListenerDigital) event -> {
    try {
        if (event.getState() == PinState.HIGH) {
            socketConnection.writeData("String that should be sent within 10 seconds");
            timeoutHandler.cancel(true);
            timeoutScheduler.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

timeoutScheduler.awaitTermination(10_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
turnstileClosed.removeAllListeners();
```